# Disable windows key - electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to disable the windows key on my electron app . Is there any way to disable windows key. I have tried global shortcuts but it is not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Are you making some sort of kiosk application?

Comment: @Brad yes, exactly. I want to disable user to exit the app or shutdown pc when the app is running.

Comment: There is probably more you'll have to do on the system level.  Have you considered setting your Electron app as the shell, so that explorer.exe isn't even running?

Comment: @Brad
No , not yet. Haven't considered that.
I will take a look at that. Any reference for that ?
And any idea about disabling windows keys ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Answer (score 1):

The windows key in Electron is the Super key. Create a globalshortcut for that, and you're good to go. It will now be redirected to your app when it is pressed.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator#available-modifiers

Comment: I tried, but when passing only Super in globalshortcut is throwing error.

Comment: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from super.